# TCP receive usage 100% CPU

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp, cpu-usage

I reading high frequency data through tcp and with following code

```
 while (1) {
    lrev = recv(fd, buff, 80, MSG_WAITALL);
    dowork();
 }
```

I am running this code through a thread and assigned this thread to a specific CPU core. I can see that the particular core using 100% CPU. Is it because while(1) loop ?  Is it good or bad  for the latency purpose ?

My process have 5 threads and each thread is running on separate core. My total cpu usage is around 400%.

Thanks

Comment: Check the value returned by `recv` :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I can see that the particular core using 100% CPU. Is it because while(1) loop ?

We don't see all your code, but a while(1) processing **non blocking functions** will usually spin at 100% on the CPU to which it is bounded

- Is it good or bad for the latency purpose ?

For very latency sensitive systems, it is usually good (if you want to minimize the time/latency between the arrival of a packet on the network card and the time when you started processing it)

However your call to receive with MSG_WAITALL [might block](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv), which would be bad for your latency

> This flag requests that the operation block until the full request is satisfied.

The only definitive answer to say if it is good or bad is : measure your latency in all scenarios.

EDIT:

As commented by @ Captain Obvlious, you must check the value returned by `recv`

Comment: Measure the latency and see if it's better than a conventional blocking call.

Comment: Acutally it is good and called hot burning. This type of code avoids scheduler delays due oto the tight loop and is standard in HFT scenarios. I just wonder how the OP can work in this area and be ignorant to development fundamentals on how to process data with the smallest delay possible.

Comment: Understood. I used MSG_WAITALL because  have to wait for full request. Data is coming in compressed form, unless until I receive complete one packet, i cant decompress it.

Comment: Yes but you might want to do something else with your spinning CPU while waiting for the full packet to arrive..

Comment: In other words, it is more common to not use `MSG_WAITALL` and just buffer any received data locally and then process your buffer as needed.